# Angular interpolation in HTML attribute name

Tags: html, angular, intellij-idea, interpolation

I am using IntelliJ, it understands, that {{foo}} is an interpolation in the formControlName-attribute. But in the name attribute it does not. IntelliJ thinks in the name-attribute, that {{foo}} is an array and that I am missing a : Like in {foo : bar}.

The code compiles just fine, is this an IntelliJ-Bug or am I just lucky that the compiler accepts it?

`<input type="radio" name="{{foo}}" formControlName="{{foo}}">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular definitely allows interpolation in attributes, but the generally prefered method (mostly for read ability) is property binding. `name="{{foo}}"` <=> `[name]="foo"`  [more info here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-vs-interpolation)

So your provided code

```
<input type="radio" name="{{foo}}" formControlName="{{foo}}">
```

becomes

```
<input type="radio" [name]="foo" [formControlName]="foo">
```

and this should make IntelliJ stop complaining.

Comment: Yes it did! Thanks mate :)